# При импорте из MagicaVoxel в Unity3D создаётся префаб из двух объектов

Tags: unity3d, графика

Когда я импортирую модель из MagicaVoxel в формате .obj, то получаю 3 файла:

- blue.mtl - Возможно материал (если честно хз)
- blue.obj - Моделька
- blue.png - Текстура

Потом я переношу все три файла в движок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда я переношу уже саму модель, то у меня в иерархии получается такая шняга:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо одной моей модели, у меня появляются сразу два объекта, причём модель - это объект **default**, а **blue** - тупо ящик для него. И достать модель из этого ящика мне не позволяют:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

— **Почему это происходит и как это исправить?**

Answer (score 0):

Импортировать из `MagicaVoxel` сразу в `Unity` ничего точно не нужно, это безумие. Каждая сторона каждого вокселя это два полигона, в десятки/сотни/тысячи раз больше, чем требуется, оптимизации ноль.

Никакого материала нет, `mtl` это какой-то мусор. Предположи что и текстура значения не имеет, а используется цвет вершины записанной прямо в меш.

> И достать модель из этого ящика мне не позволяют:

Кто не позволяет? Религия? Отрекись, создай самый обычный `Cube`, в компоненте `MeshFilter` выбери нужный тебе меш и все.

Comment: Про оптимизацию я наслышан. Но тут дело в другом. При импорте из MagicaVoxel в Unity, когда я уже ставлю модель на сцену в иерархии создаются сразу два объекта